# ng build -prod 404 on imported items in main.ts

Tags: angularjs, angular, systemjs, angular-cli

I am building an angular2 app with the use of angular-cli. Setting up de project was easy thanks to angular-cli.

```
> ng new my-project
> cd my-project
> ng serve -prod
```

And this works.

I added routing to my application, that's how I came across the following error.
Lets say I add a service in the app folder angular-cli has provided me with.

/src/app/my-service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MyService { }
```

And then change the main.ts so I use the service

/src/main.ts

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { MyProjectAppComponent, environment } from './app/';
import { MyService } from './app/my-service';

var service = new MyService();

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

bootstrap(MyProjectAppComponent);
```

If I now run

```
> ng serve
```

The application runs fine.
But when I run

```
> ng serve -prod
```

And go to the application I will get a 404 on my-service.ts

```
zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:4200/app/my-service.js 404 (Not Found)
```

So this is a perfect reproduction of my error. Works in dev-mode not in prod-mode.

I need this for my routing which is implemented like:

/src/app/app.routes.ts

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home.component';

const routes: RouterConfig = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent }
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
    provideRouter(routes)
];
```

/src/main.ts

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent, environment } from './app/';
import { APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from './app/app.routes';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

bootstrap(AppComponent,[
  APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS
]);
```

Then of course I get a 404 on app.routes.js

I'm using following versions:

```
node:         5.1.0
angular-cli:  0.0.39
angular:      2.0.0-rc.4
systemjs:     0.19.26
zone.js:      0.6.12
```

Comment: They closed this issue on github because they are changing angular-cli, they're gonna use webpack, pretty big change, probably breaks everything that now runs with angular-cli, but should resolve a lot of issues [git merge](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/1455)